# Is there any program (similar to Valgrind) that can be used to find the amount of statically allocated memory (given a bin file)?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, static-memory-allocation

I saw Valgrind is quite useful for things like memory leaks but it is focused more on dynamic memory. Is there any tool that can help analyze static memory?

Haven't really found any tool that can help me with my issue.

Comment: Seeking recommendations for libraries/tools is off topic here.

Comment: What is your issue, exactly?

Comment: There are tools that will dump the segments of an executable object, and their size. `nm` is one, IIRC.

Comment: @ikegami ".bin" file too?

Comment: @0___________, I am unfamiliar with a specific format associated with `.bin`. (I've seen the extension popup here and there over the years, but it was just being used generically.) But then again, the question didn't mention `.bin`.

Comment: @ikegami title dos

Comment: @ikegami FYI, `.bin` generally means using `ld --oformat=binary` or `objdump -O binary` to produce a flat image suitable for kernel boot, rom burn, etc. (e.g.) [Linking a file using ld to output a binary file gives error in OS development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37344575/5382650)

Comment: @0___________, No it doesn't. They just said they had a binary file. They might have meant `.bin`, but they did not say that.

Comment: Your question subject, and the actual text, don't agree with each other. What are you trying to do? Find out how much space your static data uses? Or detect memory errors in static data?

Answer (score 2):

Only if you have the executable file which has section information (like .elf), you can see static storage duration segments sizes.

When you compile, you can generate a map file which will show all your segments, function & variable addresses and their sizes.

You will not be able to analyze the sizes of the automatic storage duration objects

If you have only a `.bin` file - it is not possible as it does not contain any information about the program memory layout.